# Insertion of text between List of data in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, autocompletetextview

I have no idea of how would be this done in android. The image is provided [Its a ux created in html and wanted the same in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsaEl.jpg). The thing is I thought it can be attached in recycler view and coded it in this way:

```
public class FourFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView rv_notify;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Player> players=new ArrayList<>();
    TextView notify_count_tv;
    Context c;

    public FourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);
        c=v.getContext();
        notify_count_tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_notification_count);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_imageview);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_bank);
        Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bitmap);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        rv_notify= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_recyclerView);
        rv_notify.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        rv_notify.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        adapter=new MyAdapter(getContext(),players);

        players.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
            int id=i;
            if(i!=5) {
                String notify = "Your appointment for UI design has been accepted by Subajeeth Mukerjeee";
                String time = "" + i;
                String date = "17 Oct 2016";
                Player p = new Player(id, notify, time, date, R.mipmap.ic_bank);
                players.add(p);
            }else {
                rv_notify.setAdapter(adapter);
                players.clear();
                TextView textView = new TextView(c);
                textView.setText("123");
                String notify = "Your appointment for UI design has been accepted by Subajeeth Mukerjeee";
                String time = "" + i;
                String date = "17 Oct 2016";
                Player p = new Player(id, notify, time, date, R.mipmap.ic_bank);
                players.add(p);
            }
        }

        if(!(players.size()<1)){
            notify_count_tv.setText(""+players.size());
            rv_notify.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        return v;
    }

    public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
        float BLUR_RADIUS = 23.3f;
        if (null == image) return null;

        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
        final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(getContext());
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

        //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
        return outputBitmap;
    }

}
```

but the view only print the last remaining data left replacing the other.
I also tried to insert a textview in middle to get result of the image but dat too failed. Can you help me make the same as the image provided in android?

Comment: You have to use [pinned-section-listview](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview) refer it.

Comment: Thanks it was the type i wanted. Can it be done through recycle view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [sticky-headers-recyclerview](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) for section headers with list.